# multi-relation queries in SQL

Tags: sql

Given these four relations:

```
Mentorship (mentee_id, mentor_id)
Study (sid, credits)
Enrollment (did, sid)
Student (sid, street , city )
```

I want to write a query that finds all students who live in the same city and street as their mentor, assuming that all mentors and mentees are students.

I tried to write this query as:

```
SELECT sid
FROM Student, Mentorship
WHERE street IN (SELECT sid
                 FROM Student, Mentorship
                 WHERE mentor_sid = sid 
                   AND ...   )
```

It's incomplete but I tried to SELECT a sid from Student and Mentorship relations where street falls into a condition where `mentor_sid` and `mentee_sid` has same street and city.

I am new to SQL and still confused how to do these stuffs.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: this is just a general SQL query

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join student (mentee) to student (mentor) via the link table

```
SELECT s1.* FROM Student s1
INNER JOIN Mentorship m ON s1.sid = m.mentee_id
INNER JOIN student s2 ON s2.sid = m.mentor_id 
   AND s2.street = s1.street AND s2.city = s1.city
```

Comment: Thanks! I am quite not familiar with INNER JOIN. Is this same as putting all conditions in a WHERE clause?

Comment: see the link that @marc_s has put on your question

Comment: Old style would be SELECT s1.* FROM Student s1, mentorship m, student s2
where s1.sid = m.mentee_id
and s2.sid = m.mentor_id 
AND s2.street = s1.street AND s2.city = s1.city   but as marc_s said, you should be using ANSI standard joins